# System cannot find the file specified when I try to call an executable file in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, winscp

I'm running a C# script in SSIS. 
In that script, I'm trying to call winSCP.com which is located in the following directory: "C:\Program Files (86)\WinSCP\"

But when I try to run the code, it always fails immediately.
Here is my code. what am I doing wrong?

```
// Run hidden WinSCP process

Process winscp = new Process();
winscp.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\";
winscp.StartInfo.FileName = "winSCP.com";
winscp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
winscp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
winscp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
winscp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
winscp.Start();
```

> The Error: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file              specified at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winscp.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.com";`

Comment: While this might be the correct answer, please provide an explanation of why this will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you.  I commented out the StartInfo.WorkingDirectory line and added the full path as shown in your answer which worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not use shell execute. You must use the full path to the executed file. Because that in this case the working directory is not base directory to relative path. But just working folder for the executed file.